# starling on iOS - Touch Event not working

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash

I implemented a touch event on in my Game Class (not Main Class).

```
addEventListener(starling.events.TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);

function onTouch(e:starling.events.TouchEvent) {

     var touch:Touch = e.getTouch(stage) as Touch; 

}
```

When testing in the mobile emulator in FlashDevelop, the handler works.

When testing on iPad running iOS 7, it does not fire.

Did I miss anything?

I have this at the beginning of the Main.as:

```
// touch or gesture?
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

    Starling.multitouchEnabled = true;
```

Mirza

Comment: I got ti working by adding stage to the listener, stage.addEventListener(starling.events.TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);

Comment: now the problem is that the event is fired, but the stuff inside is not performed, but it works in the emulator

Comment: Did you try using this instead of stage?   var touch:Touch = e.getTouch(this, TouchPhase.ENDED);

Comment: PLlease do not ask the same question multiple times:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122226/starling-on-ios-touch-event-handler-dies-off

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us what you are trying to perform inside the event handler, as your problem is now with that code.

All you're doing in your question is creating a pointer to the touch event.

Comment: Im applying force to a biy2d body

Answer (score 0):

I'm applying force to a box2d body, I got it working in the FlashDevelop emulator, but it does not work on iOS device:

```
if (touch && touch.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED) {

                //do something


                    var mouseX_m:Number = touch.globalX;
            var mouseY_m:Number = touch.globalY;

            var xDiff:Number = mouseX_m - (_whiteBall.GetPosition().x * WORLD_SCALE);
            var yDiff:Number = mouseY_m - (_whiteBall.GetPosition().y * WORLD_SCALE);

            var angle:Number = Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff);
            var angleDeg = angle * 180 / Math.PI;


            //que_mc.rotation = angleDeg;

            var len = Math.sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff));

            var vx = len * Math.cos(angle);
            var vy = len * Math.sin(angle);

            var vel = _whiteBall.GetLinearVelocity();

            vel.x += (vx * 5);
            vel.y += (vy * 5);


                //apply force
                var force = new b2Vec2(vel.x, vel.y);
                _whiteBall.SetAwake(vel);
                _whiteBall.SetLinearVelocity(force);



            }
```

Comment: Update your question with this info, do not add an answer.